# right substitution to perform this integral

Tags: integration

I tried to perform the integral $\int_{a-c}^{a+c}\!\sqrt{c^{2}-(r-a)^{2}}\, r^{3}dr$ by doing integration by parts and by  substituting $r-a=c\tan\theta$ but it gets complicated. Any easy method to solve it ?

Comment: the solution looks ugly

Comment: we get this here after the substitution above $\frac{1}{8} \pi a c \sqrt{c^2} \left(4 a^2+3 c^2\right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better substitution would be $r-a=c\sin(\theta)$. In that case the integral becomes
$$\int{|c||\cos(\theta)|(\sin(\theta)+a)^3\cos(\theta)d\theta}$$
You can expand $(\sin(\theta)+a)^3$ as
$$\sin^3(\theta)+3\sin^2(\theta)a+3\sin(\theta)a^2+a^3$$
This makes the integral quite manageable (though you may have to split it into positive and negative parts because of the $|\cos(\theta)|$.

Comment: I think the substitution $r-a=c\tan\theta$ is of the same complexity but it is better since $\sec\theta$ remains positive in the interval $-\pi/4$ to $\pi/4$

Comment: Cosine is positive on that interval too. It's $1/\sec(\theta)$.

Comment: oh sure. that's right

Answer (score 1):

We use the substitution $r-a=c\sin\theta$
  and $dr=c\cos\theta d\theta$
  $I = \int_{a-c}^{a+c}\!\sqrt{c^{2}-(r-a)^{2}}\, r^{3}dr\,
 = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\!\sqrt{c^{2}-c^{2}\sin^{2}\theta}\,\left(c\sin\theta+a\right)^{3}c\cos\theta d\theta
= c^{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\!\cos(\theta)|{\cos\theta}|\left(c^{3}\sin^{3}\theta+a^{3}+3ac^{2}\sin^{2}\theta+3a^{2}c\sin\theta\right)d\theta
 = c^{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\!\left(c^{3}\cos^{2}\theta\sin^{3}\theta+a^{3}\cos^{2}\theta+3ac^{2}\cos^{2}\theta\sin^{2}\theta+3a^{2}c\cos^{2}\theta\sin\theta\right)d\theta
 = c^{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\!\left(c^{3}\cos^{2}\theta\sin^{3}\theta+a^{3}\cos^{2}\theta+3ac^{2}\cos^{2}\theta\sin^{2}\theta+3a^{2}c\cos^{2}\theta\sin\theta\right)d\theta
 = c^{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\!\left(0+a^{3}\cos^{2}\theta+3ac^{2}\cos^{2}\theta\sin^{2}\theta+0\right)d\theta
 = c^{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\!\left(a^{3}\frac{1+\cos2\theta}{2}+\frac{3}{4}ac^{2}\sin^{2}2\theta\right)d\theta
 = c^{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\!\left(a^{3}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{4}ac^{2}\frac{1-\cos4\theta}{2}\right)d\theta
 = c^{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\!\left(a^{3}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{4}ac^{2}\frac{1}{2}\right)d\theta
 = c^{2}\left(a^{3}\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{3}{4}ac^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
 = \frac{\pi}{8}ac^{2}(4a^{2}+3c^{2})
 $